# Как обнулить setInterval?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день есть такой код

```
$('#custom-dots li').on('click',function(){

    var index = $(this).index()
    $(sliderItems).slick('slickGoTo', index);
    $('#custom-dots').find('li.circle').children('.circleFill').removeClass('filled');
    $('#custom-dots').find('li.circle').eq(index).children('.circleFill').addClass('filled')

  })


  setInterval(changeCircle, 5500)
```

Функция changeCircle запускается раз в 5.5 секунд. Если к примеру функция выполнилась один раз, прошло 2 секунды, и пользователь нажал на #custom-dots li, как сделать что бы таймер у функции , обнулился и запустил функцию не через 3.5 секунды а снова через 5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var interval

function run() {
  clearInterval(interval)
  interval = setInterval(changeCircle, 5500)
}

run()
```

Answer (score 2):

setInterval возвращает идентификатор, который вы можете использовать, чтобы удалить интервал:

```
let id = setInterval(...);
...
clearInterval(id);
```